# SQL query wont order by time and date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlsrv

I am working on my sql query where I order by time and date but unsure why it's not ordering correct. Its showing date 29 before 30.:

```
SELECT measurements.title as Tittel, routines.value as Verdi, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),routines.date,103) as Dato, convert(VARCHAR(10), routines.time, 108) as Tid, pools.name as Basseng, emps.user_name as Ansatt
FROM routines, measure_routine, measurements, pools, emps
WHERE routines.id = measure_routine.routine_id
AND measure_routine.measure_id = measurements.id
AND (measurements.title  Like 'T_%') AND measure_routine.pool_id=pools.id AND routines.emp_id=emps.id 
AND Date between '2014-04-29' and '2014-04-30'
order BY routines.date, routines.time
```

Comment: Could you please include sample data and the output that you currently get? It would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because it's sorting ascending.  If you want 29 after 30, then you need descending.

```
SELECT measurements.title as Tittel, routines.value as Verdi, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),routines.date,103) as Dato, convert(VARCHAR(10), routines.time, 108) as Tid, pools.name as Basseng, emps.user_name as Ansatt
FROM routines, measure_routine, measurements, pools, emps
WHERE routines.id = measure_routine.routine_id
AND measure_routine.measure_id = measurements.id
AND (measurements.title  Like 'T_%') AND measure_routine.pool_id=pools.id AND routines.emp_id=emps.id 
AND Date between '2014-04-29' and '2014-04-30'
order BY routines.date desc, routines.time desc
```

Comment: That did sort on date but not on time.

Comment: What's the invalid output you're receiving?  Maybe add this info as an edit to your question...